# Was there a secret plot by the US government to stage a false flag attack in Syria to blame Assad?

Tags: propaganda

[Strategic Culture Foundation](http://www.globalresearch.ca/hillary-clinton-approved-delivering-libyas-sarin-gas-to-syrian-rebels-seymour-hersh/5522647) alleges that there was a secret plot by Hillary Clinton and the US government to stage a false flag attack on Syria to blame Assad:

> However, now, for the first time, Hersh has implicated Hillary Clinton directly in this «rat line». In an interview with Alternet.org, Hersh was asked about the then-US-Secretary-of-State’s role in the Benghazi Libya US consulate’s operation to collect weapons from Libyan stockpiles and send them through Turkey into Syria for a set-up sarin-gas attack, to be blamed on Assad in order to ‘justify’ the US invading Syria, as the US had invaded Libya to eliminate Gaddafi. Hersh said: «That ambassador who was killed, he was known as a guy, from what I understand, as somebody, who would not get in the way of the CIA. As I wrote, on the day of the mission he was meeting with the CIA base chief and the shipping company. He was certainly involved, aware and witting of everything that was going on. And there’s no way somebody in that sensitive of a position is not talking to the boss, by some channel».

Did such plot exist?

Note: Strategic Culture Foundation is a [Kremlin funded](https://meduza.io/en/feature/2015/08/14/the-kremlin-s-manichaean-delusion) think tank that primarily creates pro-Russian content. Some of which are explicitly racist.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Comment: The question seems misleading: it implies Clinton sent **US** sarin gas to Syria, but that is not what is claimed.

Comment: @CPerkins: He got his account temporarily suspended "because of low-quality contributions". I guess the 1-rep and avatar reset are side effects of that.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no evidence to support this conclusion. What [Hersch's article](https://www.lrb.co.uk/v36/n08/seymour-m-hersh/the-red-line-and-the-rat-line) actually suggests is that Al-Nusra may have produced sarin in Syria. It had support from Turkey and possibly Saudi Arabia, but not the United States.